# Watch for elements with specific attribute

Tags: javascript, triggers, mutation-observers, mutation

I have a web application that has an index.html that loads data via ajax to show different pages.

On those different pages I want to place `data-watch="true"` attributes on some elements that need to be watched for changes (including itself and its children). For example:

```
<ul data-watch="true">
    <li>this</li>
    <li>is</li>
    <li>a</li>
    <li>test</li>
</ul>
```

If the `ul` itself changes, or the children of that `ul` are added/changed/deleted I need to execute a function that shows what's been changed. The `ul` is an example. This could also be a div with loads of childs in it (also childs in childs etc).

After some research I found that using a Mutation Observer is the best way to go for this. However, I don't quite get it to work yet with the mutation observer alone. Then I found a library called **Mutation Summary** that claims it can do what I want. I just can't get it to work in the way I want to.

Right now I have this:

```
var observer = new MutationSummary({
    callback: handleChanges,
    queries: [{
        attribute: 'data-watch',
    }]
});
function handleChanges(summaries){
    console.log(summaries);
}
```

But with this code `handleChanges` doesn't get triggered when the `ul` is loaded in via ajax.

However, when I add the attribute to each `li`, then it does work. But I don't want to define the attributes on each element that needs to be inspected. Just put it on a parent element that keeps track all its children. This seems the most logic to me at least...

If you have a solution without the [MutationSummary](https://github.com/rafaelw/mutation-summary) library, that's totally fine. As long as all changes (added, changed or deleted) on the elements with the `data-watch="true"` attribute (and it's children) are triggered.

Could you help me with this matter?

Answer (score 0):

JQuery allows you to add event listeners on multiple elements at a time. A selector like $("ul[data-watch='true']") should encapsulate the elements you're interested in. If you wrap an event listener in a domready statement inside your ajax call's success callback, your handler should function as expected. It would look something like this:

```
$.ajaxSetup({cache:false, success:function(){
  $(document).ready(handler);
}});

function handler(){
  $("[data-watch='true']").each(function(){
    this.style.cursor = "pointer";
    $(window).on("click", this,function(){
      console.log("I'm now listening!");
    });
  });
};
```

You can see a demo [here](http://codepen.io/imafeature/pen/XdXwEQ?editors=1111), the ajax courtesy of Vital Dev Team.

As for the reason your code isn't currently working, I'm not familiar with MutationSummary, but I imagine the problem has something to do with trying to use asynchronous values in a synchronous context. It's important to listen for changes from a static scope.

Note that the "change" dom event is limited to forms, so alerting the system to changes will require [a little more code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver). You'd probably end up using the MutationObserver in the `.each()` method rather than a traditional event listener. Not sure if that's easier or harder than what you're trying to do.

Anyway, I hope some of that helps!

Comment: Good thinking! However, isn't the success function overwritten if that is called elsewhere in the code?

Comment: Well the global .ajaxSuccess() can be overwritten, but my understanding is that you must do so explicitly when making the call as I did above, in which case, your function is the one doing the overwriting.